# Spring @Pattern bean validation with localised pattern?

Tags: java, spring, localization

Our Spring MVC application uses the @Pattern annotation on view beans to restrict the characters our users can enter.

```
@Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z0-9_.]*")
private String username;
```

We are localising the application to various European languages (French, German, etc) and want  to include other characters like those with accents and umlauts.

I get the feeling we should concentrate on excluding the characters we don't want or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use this pattern [\\p{IsL}] for Unicode characters. It includes accents (á é í ó ú) and other European characters (ñ ...)

Answer (score 0):

I think `\p{L}` is what you are a looking for. That's the character class for unicode characters. See also the docs for the Pattern class.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using this pattern:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_.\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]*$")
private String username;
```

be aware, that it includes non-European languages as well.
Although, `\p{L}` should also work fine:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[\\p{L}0-9_.]*$")
private String username;
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html